# UITableView inform UITableViewCell about reload

Tags: uitableview, reloaddata

Here is a short summary of the situation:

I have a TableViewController with a number of cells.
In one of the cells I have a UITextField. This cell is of a custom UITableViewCell class. This class implements the UITextFieldDelegate protocol and the method `textFieldDidEndEditing:`
Within the method `textFieldDidEndEditing:` I store the value of the TextField into CoreData.

This all works great.

My question relates to reloading the TableView:

After certain actions of the user I reload the data of the UITableView by calling `[self.tableView reloadData]`
If, when I call this method,  the above mentioned TextField is first responder, the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method will be called, causing my CoreData related code to execute.

When the TableView is being reloaded I do not want the custom TabelViewCell to do anything at all.
Is there a way, the TableViewCell  can be aware of the TableView being reloaded? So I can check for this within the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method?

In the meantime I have solved it in the following way:

When this TableViewCell is being created I let the ViewController store a reference to it.
Before calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` I first inform the Cell by setting a custom property `_cell.tableWillReload = YES`
I will check for this property within the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method.

I was thinking maybe there is a different, more default way, for TableViewCells to know they surroundingTableView is reloading?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
[yourTextFieldOfCell resignFirstResponder];
```

before calling `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Calling `resignFirstResponder` results in `textFieldDidEndEditing` being called. The result is still the same. I do not want the code in `textFieldDidEndEditing` to be executed.